# php mail multiple return addresses

Tags: php, email, return

I have searched http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and also a few other top searched to Google to no avail. I'm thinking this functionality is not possible but would like to ask just in case I am wrong.

Can PHP MAIL send to multiple return addresses in the case of bounce-back emails?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Your best bet would be to set a generic "From" address that simply forwards to a list of email addresses on your mail server.

Comment: As far as I know, no. You need to create a "distribution list" on your mail-server for a particular address.